# Scroll only one section in a UICollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In a UICollectionView which has three sections, how can I scroll only the third section and prevent the other two sections from scrolling.

Is there any possibility.

Comment: you can't do that directly – you'll need to find a bit more complex approach.

Comment: Can you please suggest me if you know that complex approach.

Comment: that depends on the goal... if you could share more details about what kinda UI (=layout) you'd intend to assemble together it would be easier to find a suitable solution for you.

Comment: with no code given, i assume you want to scroll only bottom part of your view then you can avoid first two section in UIScrollview and take them as a simple View and make it fix on top of colleciton view. and add scrollable content to collection view. if you want all in collection view its not a straight forwad and you need to dig deep.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will move the non scrollable part to UIView as suggest by @WasimMalek.

Comment: If you make a tableView of collectionViews then the set can scroll vertically and each section can (if you choose) scroll horizontally,  Set the VC as the tableview AND collectionView datasource and delegate.  See the airbnb app as an example of this ui.